# Show ImageField in Angular template

Tags: angularjs, django, django-models, imagefield

I'm using Django with Angular to build a blog, and would like to use Django's built-in ImageField.  `<img src="{{ post.image }}">` is not rendering the image though.  It is rendering the other fields though (This HTML - `<span>{{ post.title }}</span>` - works fine).

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(editable=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.title
```

[File strucrture>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RwpO.png)

Comment: try `<img src="{{ post.image.url }}">`  When you have a problem like this: Inspect image -> Check value of `src`. If there is no link/a bad one ou can search for the problem

Comment: That helped I think.  It went from rendering nothing to a broken link icon.

Comment: is `/media/` in the link?

Comment: It's not.  I'm not sure how to set up a media dir using angular.  I linked a screenshot of my directory structure.  Can you point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure you have set [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) in your settings.py as the absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
- During development, be sure you have added *settings.MEDIA_URL* in your urls.py, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)